# XSS inside the array methods?

Tags: javascript, dom, xss

I have one user Inputted place (Search box) in my code

`let searchText = document.getElementById('search').value`

and that input is used to search inside the array of objects using indexOf method as the following

`let searchTextIndex = data.map((obj)=>obj.Artist.toLowerCase()).indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase())`

I tried `);alert('XSS'`  to escape the indexOf method but that doesn't trigger so is it possible to XSS this. What am I missing or need to understand here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XSS attacks work when the user input is used to **generate code**.

To take a trivial and unrealistic example:

```
const userInput = "' + doSomethingEvil() '";
const string_to_eval = "alert('You said: " + userInput + "')";
eval(string_to_eval);
```

The userInput contains quote marks which break out of the string literal the string is intended to be placed inside. The string is then evaluated by eval as code.

More commonly such an attack takes advantage of user input being injected into an HTML document. Here’s a typical PHP example (consider $name to come from $_GET instead of being hard coded).

```
<?php $name = "<script>doSomethingEvil();</script>"; ?>
<p>Hello <?php echo $name; ?></p>
```

The code you’ve written **never evaluates the userInput as part of code**. It’s just data that you manipulate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! According to your answer, I seems to misunderstand about the XSS attack. My understanding of XSS is escaping the original javascript code from user inputted area. But it seems, the code itself needs to include those inputs (code) back to the DOM for XSS to be exploitable. is my understanding correct here?

Comment: No. It needs to be evaluated as code. The eval based example goes nowhere near the DOM.

Comment: Oh ok, I have also read articles about attacking by inserting html tags so a little confused rn. I need to explore more.